# Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I need to grab two IP addresses from hosts file.  I'm new to regular expressions and using the following code.  Its working but it's grabbing all the IP's listed.

When running the below script this is the results:

102.54.94.97
38.25.63.10
127.0.0.1
10.104.134.41
10.104.134.42
10.0.45.90
10.0.45.92
10.0.45.93
10.0.45.94
10.0.45.95
10.0.45.96
10.0.45.97
10.0.45.98

```
$input_path = ‘c:\temp\Hosts’
$output_file = ‘c:\temp\test.txt’
$regex = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { 
$_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

What I'm expecting is to grab just two of the IP's:

10.104.134.41 &
10.104.134.42

The first octets will always be 10 and the last octets will always be .41 & .42

Comment: $regex = ‘\b10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.4[12]\b’ ?

Comment: Please edit your title to make it more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Im still working thru how all the variables work.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression currently has no restriction on the first/last octet.

`$regex = '\b10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.4[12]\b'`

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/WUFYwx/1)